# как изменить содержимое html элемента с помощью php по id

Tags: javascript, php, html

У меня такая проблема. Как по id у элемента (Например: элемент p с id= "id") заменить его содержимое(One), значением php(Например на "Two").

Comment: А как вы пробовали?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: С помощью php - никак

Comment: Это очень удобно делать на JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть Вам нужен [HTML парсер на PHP](https://github.com/simplehtmldom/simplehtmldom)? ([Документация](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm))

```
<?php

// Создаём DOM из строки
$html = str_get_html('
  <div id="hello">Hello</div>
  <div id="world">World</div>
');

// Ищем элемент 'div' с 'id="hello"' и меняем его содержимое на 'foo'
$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';

// Ищем второй элемент 'div' по порядку и добавляем ему класс 'bar'
$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';

echo $html; 
// Результат:
// <div id="hello">foo</div>
// <div id="world" class="bar">World</div>

?>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо.  Это то что мне нужно было.